# How to trigger an EventToCommand from a GestureListener.Gesture

Tags: mvvm-light

Has anyone used a Toolkit.GestureListener to fire an EventToCommand?

Comment: Nick, Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it with the EventToCommand behaviour but I have created a behaviour that allows easy addition of the GestureListener by binding them to a command.

```
<Button  Content="Start"  
 Behaviour:GestureListenerBehaviours.TapCommand="{Binding   StartCommand}" />
```

I have only mapped the tap and the double tap but it should be easy to map the rest if required. Have a look at this link to get the source code

http://lazycowprojects.tumblr.com/post/10397441921/gesturelistenerbehaviourswp7

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible. GestureListener.Tap does not support this.
I have an event handler in my code behind, which calls viewmodel method using datacontext:

```
 private void OnListItemTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
 {
     var vm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
     if (vm != null)
     {
         vm.TapOnItem.Execute(listbox.SelectedItem);
     }
 }
```