# Detect and handle Gestures in WP8 using MVVMLight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

## Problem

I'm currently trying to find a MVVMLight compatible way to use gestures in my WP8 app. Specifically I just want to detect a swipe/flick and bind it to a RelayCommand in my view model. Has there been any recent solution developed over the years that I'm unaware of?

## Prior Research

I've done some research before hand, and the results I've come up with are mostly outdated or no longer exist. i.e:

1. [Old Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813608/how-to-trigger-an-eventtocommand-from-a-gesturelistener-gesture)
2. [Clarity Consulting Blog Post with non-existant code](http://blogs.claritycon.com/windowsphone7/2010/07/wp7-gesture-recognizer-and-behavior-triggers/)
3. `toolkit:GestureListener` from the Windows Phone Toolkit supports gestures but requires you to couple the ViewModel with the View.

### Edit

Note: Found out that `toolkit:GestureListener` has been deprecated.

Comment: Have you considered writing a `Behavior` that couples the Gesture listener with a `RelayCommand`?

Comment: Any suggestion on how I would go around doing that?

Comment: do you have much experience writing custom Behaviours? That will be a great place to start. They are `DependencyObject`s so you can compose them in xaml and databind them to your viewmodel's `RelayCommand`s.

Comment: I will try to work on it, will answer my question if I get a solution

Comment: Thanks for the help, but found a much easier method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question.

Instead of using `toolkit:GestureListener`, I found out that `EventToCommand` with `ManipulationDelta` or `ManipulationCompleted` works as well:

## In XAML

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationDelta">
    <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SlideOutDeltaCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationCompleted">
    <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SlideOutCompletedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

By passing in EventArgs to the ViewModel, you can detect whether a swipe gesture has been issued:

## In ViewModel

#### Define RelayCommand

```
 public RelayCommand<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs> SlideOutDeltaCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

#### Define Execute() Method

```
 private void OnSlideDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var delta = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation;

        //If Change in X > Change in Y, its considered a horizontal swipe
        var isDeltaHorizontal = Math.Abs(delta.X) > Math.Abs(delta.Y) ? true : false;
    }
```

#### Register your Command in ViewModel Constructor

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SlideOutDeltaCommand = new RelayCommand<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>((e) => OnSlideDelta(e));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Joost Van Schaaik created such a behaviour on wp7: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2011/03/simple-windows-phone-7-silverlight.html

He can be contacted on twitter by [@localjoost](https://twitter.com/LocalJoost)